# Adding labels to Menu icon in Action Bar

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-menu

At the moment I have a pretty standard action bar with a menu icon. I'd like to do something like this, an overlay

[image: Menu icon with number]

I also tried a little experiment by using a toolbar and going with this, but no luck:

toolbar.setNavigationIcon(R.drawable.ic_document_hit);

Any thoughts?

Answer (score -1):

in this link [here](http://www.hermosaprogramacion.com/2015/06/tablayout-como-anadir-pestanas-en-android/) there is an example where it is done, the problem is that is in spanish, but you can download the code to check how do it, You have to create a java class that extends from drawable. I hope be useful for you.

Comment: this doesn't answer the question, the item shown in the link is a menu item not the menu drawer icon.